# Call method of an array from golang template

Tags: arrays, templates, go, methods, go-templates

So in my `main.go` I have a struct and a method that I can call from inside `main.go` without a problem. Imagine it being like this:

```
type Test struct {
    val1 float32
    val2 float32
}

func (t Test) callMethod() float32 {
    return t.val1 / t.val2
}
```

I am calling the template like this and as data I am giving an array of the `Test` structs, like this:

```
var testvar1 Test
var testvar2 Test
var teststructs [] Test
teststructs = append(teststructs, testvar1)
teststructs = append(teststructs, testvar2)
tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "testpage.gohtml", teststructs)
```

Inside the template I am trying to call the `callMethod` like this

```
{{range .}}
    {{ .callMethod }}
{{end}}
```

But I am getting the following error:

> executing "testpage.gohtml" at <.callMethod>: can't evaluate field callMethod in type main.Test

Has anyone an Idea what I am doing wrong and has a solution for this? I am trying to fix it since many hours and I am so frustrated at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Test`struct has no exported fields/methods, i.e. fields/methods within the struct that are used within the template have to start with a capital letter.

Update the method name to `CallMethod`

```
func (t Test) CallMethod() float32 {
    return t.val1 / t.val2
}
```

and the template:

```
const tmpl = `
{{range .}}
   {{.CallMethod}}
{{end}}
`
```

see the code https://play.golang.org/p/Vud7ipJ_Vyr